# What is the difference between xact_start and query_start in postgresql?

Tags: postgresql

I am reviewing over the pg_stat_activity view. And there are two fields that are indistinguishable to me:

> xact_start:The time at which the transaction started to run which
>   could be different than the query_start but should always have
>   occurred before the query_start time.
>
> query_start: The time at which the query started to run. This can be
>   useful to determine if a query has been running for a long time.

It says they both determine the start time of the query. It also says that xact_start can be different than query_start, but doesn't explain why - only that it should start prior to query_start. But what is the actual difference between the two? Why would I care about xact_start?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> It also says that xact_start can be different than query_start, but
>   doesn't explain why

It differs when the transaction encapsulates several queries, for example:

```
BEGIN;  -- starts at t0, beginning of transaction
query1; -- starts at t1
query2; -- starts at t2
COMMIT; -- starts at t4, end of transaction
```

If we look at the `pg_stat_activity` entry for this session while `query2` is running, `xact_starts` will be `t0` and `query_start` will be `t2`, with `t2>t0`, the difference being essentially the duration of `query1`.

`xact_start` helps discovering long running transactions, which is useful when troubleshooting or tuning a live database.

Comment: doe that mean when Query2 runs, it willl Update the query_start column of the table with the new time?